# How to know Incoming Email Message ID to get message contents

Tags: android, jakarta-mail

I want to get Incoming Email Message ID for get message contents. I've applied this code to listen change in message counts.

```
folder.addMessageCountListener(new MessageCountListener() {

            public void messagesAdded(MessageCountEvent e) {
                System.out.println("Message Count Event Fired");
            }

            public void messagesRemoved(MessageCountEvent e) {
                System.out.println("Message Removed Event fired");
            }
        });

        folder.addMessageChangedListener(new MessageChangedListener() {

            public void messageChanged(MessageChangedEvent e) {
                System.out.println("Message Changed Event fired");
            }
        });
```

the above code works fine for IMAP server, whenever a message added or removed. But i want to know which Message has been removed or Added.

Kindly help. the full code is,

MainActivity:

```
String host = "imap.gmail.com";
String mailStoreType = "imap";
String username = "EmailAddress@gmail.com";
String password = "****";

CheckingMails.check(host, mailStoreType, username, password);
```

CheckingMails:

```
public class CheckingMails {

public static void check(String host, String storeType, String user,
                         String password) {
   boolean supportsIdle = false;
        IMAPFolder folder = null;
        int freq = 2000;
        try {

            Properties props = System.getProperties();
            props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");
            Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
            final javax.mail.Store store = session.getStore("imaps");

            store.connect(host, user, password);

            folder = (IMAPFolder) store.getFolder("Inbox");
            folder.open(IMAPFolder.READ_WRITE);
            Log.d("fhjg43524318778", folder.toString());

            try {
                folder = (IMAPFolder) store.getFolder("Inbox");
                folder.open(IMAPFolder.READ_WRITE);
                SearchTerm sender = new FromTerm(new InternetAddress("zohaibsvu@gmail.com"));

                // Getting from specific email
                Message[] message = folder.search(sender);

                Log.d("fghjgh564", String.valueOf(message.length));

                for (int i = 1; i < message.length; i++) {
                    Message writePart = message[i];
                    int id = message[i].getMessageNumber();
                    String from = message[i].getFrom()[0].toString();
                    String subject = message[i].getSubject();
                    Log.d("dfgh3423", "# "+id+" From "+from+", subject "+subject);
                }
            } catch (AddressException  y) {

            } catch (MessagingException u) {

            }

        folder.addMessageCountListener(new MessageCountListener() {

            public void messagesAdded(MessageCountEvent e) {
                    Log.d("asfd3565678", "Message Count Event Fired");
            }

            public void messagesRemoved(MessageCountEvent e) {
                    Log.d("asfd3565678", "Message Count Event Fired");
            }
        });

        folder.addMessageChangedListener(new MessageChangedListener() {

            public void messageChanged(MessageChangedEvent e) {
                    Log.d("asfd3565678", "Message Count Event Fired");
            }
        });


        // Check mail once in "freq" MILLIseconds
        int freq = 2000;
        boolean supportsIdle = false;
        try {
            if (emailFolder instanceof IMAPFolder) {
                IMAPFolder f = (IMAPFolder) emailFolder;
                f.idle();
                supportsIdle = true;
            }
        } catch (FolderClosedException fex) {
            throw fex;
        } catch (MessagingException mex) {
            supportsIdle = false;
        }
        for (; ; ) {
            if (supportsIdle && emailFolder instanceof IMAPFolder) {
                IMAPFolder f = (IMAPFolder) emailFolder;
                f.idle();
                System.out.println("IDLE done");
            } else {
                Thread.sleep(freq); // sleep for freq milliseconds

                // This is to force the IMAP server to send us
                // EXISTS notifications.
                emailFolder.getMessageCount();
            }
        }



        /*
        // retrieve the messages from the folder in an array and print it
        Message[] messages = emailFolder.getMessages();
        System.out.println("messages.length---" + messages.length);

        for (int i = 0, n = messages.length; i < n; i++) {
            Message message = messages[i];
            System.out.println("---------------------------------");
            System.out.println("Email Number " + (i + 1));
            System.out.println("Subject: " + message.getSubject());
            System.out.println("From: " + message.getFrom()[0]);
            System.out.println("Text: " + message.getContent().toString());

        }

        */

        //close the store and folder objects
     //   emailFolder.close(false);
     //   store.close();

    } catch (NoSuchProviderException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}





}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Message-ID is accessible via the [MimeMessage.getMessageID](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeMessage.html#getMessageID--) method.

If you were really asking about the IMAP UID, that's accessible via the [UIDFolder.getUID](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/javax/mail/UIDFolder.html#getUID-javax.mail.Message-) method.  Cast the Folder object to UIDFolder.

Comment: How to implement MimeMessage.getMessageID() into folder.addMessageCountListener(new MessageCountListener(); to get newly arrived message id?

Comment: You get notified with the Message object.  Cast it to MimeMessage and call the method.  What do you want to do with the I’d after you store it in the database?

Comment: I want to make offline copy into database because loading all emails on every apps opening takes alot of time. thats why i'll save it into database. Then when any changes occur on server, reflect it into database.

Comment: you're requested to please suggust me good way or any online example to make offline mail apps.

Comment: That’s a much bigger question than can be answered here.  You need to do more research first and then ask a specific question.  Have you read the JavaMail FAQ yet?